# How to create integer of a certain length with Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've tried two approaches and both are not working, I searched on Google and didn't find any proper solutions. My code looks like:

```
intField = Column(SmallInt(), length=5)
```

And the error says:

```
Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['length']
```

I also tried, knowing it shouldn't work, this solution:

```
intField = Column(SmallInt(5))
```

And it does not work because this SqlAlchemy datatype doesn't accept arguments.

Any ideas?

**[Update]**

I'm using `MySQL` as database engine, so the solution here is to import mysql's own Integer type, and then specify the length I want it to be.

In the above example, I would only need to do:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

Integer = mysql.INTEGER 

class ...
    ...
    intField = Column(Integer(5))
```

But I still wonder if there is a more generic approach?

Comment: Why a numeric field instead of a `String(6)` with validations to accept only numbers?

Comment: Validating, converting, and any related operations will add overhead. Plus operating on integers are faster when calculations are involved. I guess using `code` as an attribute here is a little misleading, let me change that to better explain my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has the [DECIMAL/NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) type.

Use `Decimal(5, 0)` to a field with 5 digits.

Use this only if you really need a number. If won't do math with this field, prefer a `String(5)` and validate the digits (`isdigit()` is your friend).

In SQLAlchemy, handle it as a [`Numeric` field](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric).

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion, using zip code is a bad example. I meant to ask if I do want to do calculation with this field, and ALSO want to specify a column width for it. What would I do?

Comment: @benjaminz use for example the `DECIMAL(5, 0)`. In SQLAlchemy, it is a `Numeric` field. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric

Comment: This can be a proper solution, could you update your answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I also replaced zipcode with **intField** to avoid  confusion for others.